# Google analytics impossible session

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am adding Google Analytics to my Android app. The app was published three months ago. On 23/02/2016 i have created in my google analytics page an account and a property relative to the app and linked it to my app. I still have to implement the analyitcs in my app and publish an update to google play. Today i have found that there was a session on 24/02/2016! GA says that the session is from a user from France (not my country), with an operative system of Windows Vista (??). GA can't say what is the name and the version of the app. The screen resolution was 1920x1080.
So, that session is an error or what? Where can i contact google about GA problems?

Comment: I also see these kind of reports. I've got an iOS app, and most of the reports are from my iPhone/iPad, but I've also got two suspicious reports. Both with 1920x1080 resolution, one Windows Vista & one Linux i686. Please post if you find out the root cause. There is this "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" check box in GA. Maybe these reports have been made by UNknown bots?

Comment: I have also read about the spam problem of google analytics, but i still don't understand how it is possible that some bot can create false app sessions if the app is not even published! I am really new to GA, so maybe i am missing something...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "published". If you run your app in simulator or on device I guess that GA will get a notification. Is that your problem?

Comment: I have a live app published on google play some months ago. I have setup GA creating an account and a property and linked it to my published app. Now i want to add GA code to the app and publish an update, so that tracking can start, but i still have not added the code. So the question is: how can there be session in my app if the app is still not updated?